# HTTP Error when downloading from google drive with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I've been trying to train a neural network to work with animated images, and after about two stages of training, TensorFlow attempts to download some sort of file from a google drive and then promptly fails and stops training. I'm not sure if its creating the google drive file itself as the link is different every time, or if something else is happening. Can I get some help with reading between the lines with the errors and maybe get some light shed on what the problem might be? I'm very new to this type of programming and have never worked with TensorFlow or StyleGAN before.
I've run the program multiple times with different resolutions of images and it always fails at the same part.

Log file:

```
---                  ---       ---                 ---              Total                22941313                                      

Building TensorFlow graph...  Setting up snapshot image grid...  Setting up run dir...  Training...

tick 1     kimg 140.3    lod 4.00  minibatch 128  time 11m 48s      sec/tick 661.6   sec/kimg 4.72    maintenance 46.3   gpumem 3.1  Downloading https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1MzTY44rLToO5APn8TZmfR7_ENSe5aZUn ............ failed Traceback (most recent call last):   File "train.py", line 191, in <module>
    main()   File "train.py", line 186, in main
    dnnlib.submit_run(**kwargs)   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\dnnlib\submission\submit.py", line 290, in submit_run
    run_wrapper(submit_config)   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\dnnlib\submission\submit.py", line 242, in run_wrapper
    util.call_func_by_name(func_name=submit_config.run_func_name, submit_config=submit_config, **submit_config.run_func_kwargs)   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\dnnlib\util.py", line 257, in call_func_by_name
    return func_obj(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\training\training_loop.py", line 264, in training_loop
    metrics.run(pkl, run_dir=submit_config.run_dir, num_gpus=submit_config.num_gpus, tf_config=tf_config)   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\metrics\metric_base.py", line 125, in run
    metric.run(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\metrics\metric_base.py", line 60, in run
    self._evaluate(Gs, num_gpus=num_gpus)   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\metrics\frechet_inception_distance.py", line 29, in _evaluate
    inception = misc.load_pkl('https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1MzTY44rLToO5APn8TZmfR7_ENSe5aZUn')
# inception_v3_features.pkl   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\training\misc.py", line 32, in load_pkl
    with open_file_or_url(file_or_url) as file:   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\training\misc.py", line 28, in open_file_or_url
    return dnnlib.util.open_url(file_or_url, cache_dir=config.cache_dir)   File "D:\Personal\Neural Net\stylegan-master\dnnlib\util.py", line 366, in open_url
    res.raise_for_status()   File "D:\Users\bas11\Miniconda3\envs\tfgpu-old\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://doc-08-10-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/8fm1944ik1stbbau4d65a96qqe56ta94/1576202400000/06831416635760916404/*/1MzTY44rLToO5APn8TZmfR7_ENSe5aZUn
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems, which may cause this issue:

1. Confirm that your username and password are valid for what your are trying to do (write, read etc.).
2. Try to enable APIS from google services. Sometimes these services and approvals change by the policy. For more information on APIS visit [Enable and disable APIs](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en)